# PostgreSQL column "enginePower" does not exist

Tags: sql, postgresql

I get this error when I try to use my SELECT AS name.

```
CREATE VIEW CanDrive AS
    SELECT Car.name,
    (SELECT SUM(engineParts) FROM Engine WHERE Car.engine = Engine.type) AS enginePower,

    CASE WHEN enginePower >= 30 THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' END AS canDrive

    FROM Car;
```

Why do I get the error column "enginePower" does not exist when I clearly stated it?

Comment: tried lowercasing it, still same error!

Comment: @muistooshort Do you know the problem? Since i got downvoted this post got no attention

Comment: You can’t reference other columns created at the same level. You could use a sub-query instead.

Comment: @jcaron So i have to copypaste my entire query again? `CASE WHEN (SELECT SUM(engineParts) FROM Engine WHERE Car.engine = Engine.type) >= 30 THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' END AS canDrive` Isnt that the whole reason with select as?

Answer (score 2):

`EnginePower` is derived and doesn't mean anything yet within the context of that query -- it's just an alias.  You could overcome this by evaluating the same expression as above:

```
   case
     when (SELECT SUM(engineParts) FROM Engine WHERE Car.engine = Engine.type) >= 30
       then 'yes'
     else 'no'
   end as canDrive
```

Or even better by wrapping it in a common table expression/subquery:

```
with cte as (
    SELECT
       Car.name,
      (SELECT SUM(engineParts) FROM Engine WHERE Car.engine = Engine.type) AS enginePower
    FROM Car
)
select name, enginePower, case when enginePower >= 30 then 'yes' else 'no' end as canDrive
from cte
```

Or better yet, perhaps, just convert your scalars into a standard join:

```
select
  c.name, sum (engineParts) as enginePower,
  case when sum (engineParts) >= 30 then 'yes' else 'no' end as hasPower
from
  car c
  left join engine e on
    c.engine = e.type
group by
  c.name
```